# Why doesn't khronos clean up opengl API by removing old functionality?

Tags: opengl, version

Many stuff in OpenGL is for backwards compatibility, which makes it extremely hard sometimes to make clean code.
Depending on GL version, some parameters change meaning, and some functions works differently, but mainly many functionalities are no longer needed.

For example, DSA is now part of core.
When asking a function loading library to get my function pointers, it could of course ignore whatever is simply not meant to be used, but what's against something simple like gl4CreateBuffers, etc ?
With this, functions that work differently across versions would no longer be a problem, since you'd specify which version you'd be using.
One could include a specific header for each version, when making a modular approach to opengl versions, or at least get rid of old deprecated parameters that no longer make sense in newer versions of the functions.

Inside the driver, if necessary, it could still map out to the same old functions, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

First, OpenGL has not had a version release since 2017. It seems pretty clear that the Khronos group sees OpenGL as finished or at least in maintenance mode. Major new GPU features in many cases cannot even be adapted to OpenGL's API (see raytracing). So if you're asking why any particular thing you might want done hasn't been done, the primary answer is that the owners of OpenGL aren't that interested in trying to improve it.

Second, `gl4CreateBuffers` is no more complicated than `glCreateBuffers`. The latter even has one less character. So any 1:1 function mapping isn't actually an improvement.

Third, they already tried removing stuff in GL 3.2. This helped some implementations a bit, but what constitutes "cruft" varies over time. And even this requires that users engage with the more recent APIs, which would require tutorials and so forth to be rewritten to focus on them. Which is unlikely.

Overall at this point, there simply isn't much point to it.